# How to read from a datagridview cross-thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a DataGridView control in Form1 that I am trying to force a .Refresh() and .DataSource from a class which is running in a seperate thread.

After searching google I've came up clueless since the general "cross-threading is not allowed..." error keeps persisting.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: show some code which you have tried so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986284/adding-row-to-datagridview-from-thread, this link mybe helpfull, you need to invoke datagrid to process it from another thread.

Comment: In the future, post the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SynchronizationContext is the better way now, to update Form's control from cross-threads:

CS:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _context;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // the context of MainForm, main UI thread
        // 1 Application has 1 main UI thread
        _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    private void BtnRunAnotherThreadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
                 {
                     while (true)
                     {
                         Thread.Sleep(1000);
                         //lblTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); // no work
                         UpdateTimerInMainThread(); // work
                     }
                 });
    }

    private void UpdateTimerInMainThread()
    {
        //SynchronizationContext.Current, here, is context of running thread (Task)
        _context.Post(SetTimer, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

    public void SetTimer(object content)
    {
        lblTimer.Text = (string)content;
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The access to UI elements from another threads is not allowed, so the only way you can do what you want to is using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method.

It looks like this:
//Call this code from your another thread (not UI):

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>
{
    do something in UI-thread
});
```