# WPF - Getting rid of usage of dispatcher in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, dispatcher

I have a WPF application that receives messages from a server.
I listen for messages in a background worker and if a new messages arrives I call a new event.

In my ServerMessage.xaml I had a TextBox that was bound to a property in my ViewModel.

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="{Binding ServerMessages}" />
```

In the code-behind of my ServerMessage.xaml.cs I listen for somebody to call the server-message Event.

```
public void serverMessage(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.ServerMessages += e.ServerMessage + "\r\n";
}
```

Due to certain circumstances I have to switch to a RichTextBox (mostly because of different text-color and images). 
Sadly I can't bind anything to the RichTextBox. I tried some of the available Extensions for binding but they didn't work.

To get it working I used the RichTextBox.Dispatcher in the event. It looks like this:

```
RichTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
  new Action(() => 
                  { 
                      TextPointer caretPos = ChatTextBox.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;
                      new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() {  Text = e.ServerMessage }, caretPos);
                      RichTextBox.AppendText("\u2028");
                      RichTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
                  }
            ));
```

Is there a possibility to get rid of the Dispatcher and get back to binding?

Do I gain something if I use binding or is the Dispatcher okay, too?

Comment: Instead of a RichTextBox, you may probably use an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemTemplate for the differently colored text and images. You could then bind its ItemsSource property to a (dynamically changing) collection of data item objects.

Comment: A FlowDocument and a FlowDocumentScrollViewer ?

Comment: I did an example about SynchronizationContext here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106850/how-to-read-from-a-datagridview-cross-thread-c-sharp/31141776#31141776](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106850/how-to-read-from-a-datagridview-cross-thread-c-sharp/31141776#31141776). Hope this help. It's the same for WPF.

Comment: I switched to a combination out of an ItemsControl and the SynchronizationContext. The problem is, I can't create a real ItemTemplate because every message can look completely different and I have to adapt accordingly. So I bound to an ObservableCollection<StackPanel>. The downside is that I can't create them in a Not-UI-Thread. Thats the reason why I used the SynchronizationContext to add the generated Stackpanel to the ObservableCollection and this is bound to the ItemsControl. Performance greatly improved from 15% CPU to 2% CPU.